# Windows 7 x64 Enterprise all network printers greyed out on reboot

Tags: linux, windows, networking, printing

We've got a bunch of network printers on SL7 running CUPS. These are distributed via GPP printers. This all works with older images. In the last week or so, new installs from the same base image are having issues printing.

I've checked it out, and the printers are greyed out. The print spooler is running. If I restart it, printing starts working fine, and all the printers go black again... Till the next reboot.

Now, I'm about ready to just make a startup script that restarts the print spooler to "fix" this problem, but I'm wondering if anyone has any actual solutions. The only changes are standard OS updates, and google isn't pointing to any obvious issues there.

Answer (score 0):

Try set print spooler delayted start or start up manually.
Reboot machine and check printers.
Looks like some service\network related issues.
Also verify DNS settings on machine and reset machine password in AD.

Comment: The Delayed AutoStart flag could not be set according to services.msc

Comment: Setting it to manual leads to NO printers being shown at all on boot, and you have to be admin to manually start the print spooler. However, once you do start the print spooler, all the printers work.

Comment: update machine password or re-join to domain. 

netdom resetpwd /server:DOMAINCONTROLLERNAME /userD:administrator/PasswordD *

also check (event logs) that group policy works correctly on the machine and on the server.

create anothe policy and deploy only one printer.

also you could re-deploy printers.

usually such behaivor occurs when group policy not applied or failed to applied. 

on more way to replicate:  after machine started go to \\server and connect printer manually, you should see an error, like printer not found